# Number of ways to take parentheses

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming

Say we have an expression:
$$a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}$$
how many ways can we take parentheses? (as I understand, how many evaluation orders)
I was thinking if there's $n$ number, 1st step we will need to combine any two consecutive and then we are left with $n-1$ numbers and we repeat, so I got a solution: $(n-1)!$ and I tried to verify with a simple $3+4+5$ => $((3+4)+5)$, $(3+(4+5))$ = $(3-1)!$

However I was told in this [MIT Algorithm courses on DP(parenthsization)](https://youtu.be/ocZMDMZwhCY?t=18m5s) that the number should be $4^n$, but it doesn't provide a proof...so I wonder if anyone might know its computed? and why is it different from mine?

Comment: You want to look at the Catalan Numbers. ($4^n$ is just an estimate). See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: I think my (n-1)! failed consider duplicates...(1+2)+(3+4) will be counted twice: 1st 1+2, then 3+4 vs 1st 3+4, then 1+2